# HTML 5 Audio : Is there an event that triggers when the buffered duration is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I was making custom controls for the HTML 5 Audio. I need to show the buffered duration.
The duration property gives the complete duration from the metadata, and the buffered property  is the currently buffered duration. I need to update the buffered duration as it changes. Is there an event that triggers when buffered duration of media file changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for the `progress` event.

Here is a description of all the events fired by media elements:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/media-elements.html#mediaevents

Comment: Thanks @matthias.p ! That worked. I could not make that out from the description of the event.

Comment: It looks like at least in Firefox 93 and Chromium 94 this event sometimes fires before `buffered` has actually been updated. I'm seeing both `seeked` and `progress` fire and `buffered` after a seek, and `buffered` still being the same as what it was beforehand. The only reasonable thing I've found is to also update my UI on `timeupdate`.